# Ready to use iOS UIScrollView with lazy loading of cells for displaying a "shelf" of book covers?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

I want to display a number of book and magazine covers in my app (similar to the shelf view in iBooks). So far I have implemented my own UIScrollView which displays the covers just fine - unfortunately due to performance problems, I'm forced to rewrite the whole view; however I'm sure that someone else has solved this already and probably made it an open source project (possibly part of a bigger UI toolkit/library?).

Unfortunately I didn't get far by consulting Google, Google Code and github. There are a lot of projects, most of them are examples and tests or abadoned.

So basically I'm looking for a UIScrollView based class with the following features:

- Possibility to define a cell size (of the thumbnail/cover)
- Automatic layout depending on available space
- Lazy loading (using a delegate which provides the cell contents)

Basically a UITableView, but for book shelfs.

Any pointers to existing projects or toolkits are highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I've gone looking for these before, with little fruitful output (as you said), particularly looking for a scroll right/left.  I've intended to implement one before, but it's still on the list.  --- if you just want the up/down scrolling, i've managed that before with custom cells with 4-5 icons in it.  A little math in every table view method solves the problem.  If image views, set them as userInterfaceEnabled==YES, so that you can detect taps in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing a simple UIScrollView based class which loads contents as needed. It's not too complex to do, but I guess it would be nice if something like this was implemented in the core APIs of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). In trying it out I was able to get a basic grid going pretty quickly, and there is support for bookshelves (as seen in Kobo for iPad), but I don't know how hard that would be.

**Edit:** I just noticed that it doesn't handle large quantities of items too well (after about 40 cells it started slowing down). After reading the 'Future Directions' part of the GitHub page it seems that he's going to something about it someday so it might be helpful to keep an eye on it.